# How to configure bitbucket pipeline and deploy to alibaba clouds

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have a repo on my bitbucket. I want to deploy it via bitbucket pipeline to my alibaba clouds ecs. I dont know what are steps required to manage it.

Answer (score 1):

You can be done this task using below steps:

1: Creating the Bitbucket Git Repository And Adding our Application and Docker Configurations in it

2: Integrating Bitbucket with ACR

3: Deploying The Application

4: Securing our Application with Let’s Encrypt SSL/TLS

[for full details check this:](https://medium.com/@haseeb.basil/a-basic-guide-on-how-to-deploy-an-application-to-alibaba-cloud-container-service-from-bitbucket-862139086ea4)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I look up the link of the article you provided on medium.com. I followed the steps but alibaba has discontinued docker swarm and urged to use kubernetes instead. I lost at these step. I also asked the question for the article author.